# JavaScript script loading sequence

Tags: html, parsing

I got reference of this image
[image: script loading]

But in following scenario even if the JavaScript is at the bottom of the html file its downloaded and parsed first and then the HTML is shown, I am a bit confused -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript Loader Sequence</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style1.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p>HTML parse and render</p>
    <img style="max-width: 70%; height: auto; border: 1px solid red;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfL82.png">
    <p>
        There ain't no grave can hold my body down
        There ain't no grave can hold my body down
        When I hear that trumpet sound I'm gonna rise right out of the ground
        Ain't no grave can hold my body down
    </p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Last Appearance');
    setTimeout(function(){ alert('Last appearance 5000 ms') }, 5000);
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the scripts are inline, so nothing is really downloaded. But the script is executed after the rest of the html has finished loading.
Here is a maybe clearer example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript Loader Sequence</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style1.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      alert('Head script\nThe body does not show yet');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>HTML parse and render</p>
    <img style="max-width: 70%; height: auto; border: 1px solid red;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfL82.png">
    <p>
        There ain't no grave can hold my body down
        There ain't no grave can hold my body down
        When I hear that trumpet sound I'm gonna rise right out of the ground
        Ain't no grave can hold my body down
    </p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Bottom script\nThe body has been rendered');
</script>
</html>
```

Another example, by accessing the DOM before and after it has loaded:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript Loader Sequence</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style1.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Here the paragraph has not been parsed yet and does not exist in the DOM
      alert(document.getElementById('johnnycash') && document.getElementById('johnnycash').innerText);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>HTML parse and render</p>
    <img style="max-width: 70%; height: auto; border: 1px solid red;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfL82.png">
    <p id="johnnycash">
        There ain't no grave can hold my body down
        There ain't no grave can hold my body down
        When I hear that trumpet sound I'm gonna rise right out of the ground
        Ain't no grave can hold my body down
    </p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Here the paragraph has been parsed and exists in the DOM
    alert(document.getElementById('johnnycash') && document.getElementById('johnnycash').innerText);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: For the code snippet you provided I am getting result in the following sequence -   

1. alert('Head script\nThe body does not show yet');  
  
2.  alert('Bottom script\nThe body has been rendered');  
  
3. And then the HTML is shown.  
  
I suppose after the first alert was shown, the html DOM should be shown and at last the alert at bottom, am I missing something?

Comment: Look carefully, that is not what happens. The html parser hits the first script in the head and it runs it. The alert function blocks the parsing to show the popup window. The page loading stops and nothing shows. When you dismiss the alert box, the page loading resumes. The body is rendered before the bottom script is reached and the second alert box appears.

Comment: I have added a second example

Comment: Got you point, HTML rendering and displaying have nothing to with each other, but the sequence will be followed. Thanks :)